# Error when creating Toast

Tags: android, toast

My code is

```
Context c = getApplicationContext();

CharSequence c1 = "Invalid Data Entered";

Toast t= Toast.makeText(c, c1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

t.show();
```

it showing `NULL POINTER EXCEPTION AT Toast.makeText() line`

Any help..?
thanks..

Comment: try instead of Context c this `Toast.makeText([YourClassName].this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: where is this code running ? Is it in an activity / service / .... ?

Comment: If you are using Toast from an Activity class then use Classname.this in Context

Comment: @Sfat I tried that too,.is'nt workin..

Comment: @ddewaele. its running in activity

Comment: Can you post some more source code + the stack trace you're getting

Comment: This code is called from the onCreate method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually because i was calling it from a different class and not an activity.. that was the reason.. IV can't create Toast in an Activity which is not running..

Answer (score 1):

you just have to use your view instead of getApplicationContext() for example if it is rowView just call :

```
Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext, " " ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am being blind, but the only thing I can see that could be null is your

```
getApplicationContext();
```

Check if that's null, and have it log it if it is, so you know the cause.

Can you show the code surrounding it please?

Comment: Thats just server response I'm getting.. so code around it is irrelevent.. i tried with giving "this" variable as arguement... the present class extends Activity so it obeveously is a Context..

Answer (score 0):

try this and check.

```
Context c = getBaseContext(); 
CharSequence c1 = "Invalid Data Entered";

Toast t= Toast.makeText(c, c1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

t.show();
```

or `Toast t= Toast.makeText(activity, c1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`

you can also use activity instead of context..

Answer (score 0):

Write this..

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Data Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
t.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Toast t= Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, c1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);// YourActivity is the class name
```

for showing toast.

Answer (score 0):

```
Context c=getApplicationContext();
Toast t=Toast.makeText(c, "invalid data enterd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
t.show();
```

I tried this and it is working...

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be in line `Context c = getApplicationContext();`

if context is null then you will get NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION in `Toast t= Toast.makeText(c, c1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`

You can use the following if your class extends Activity

```
Toast t= Toast.makeText(Classname.class, c1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

or

```
Toast t= Toast.makeText(this, c1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

If your class doesnot extend Activity better pass the context value to this class from the calling environment. after that use that context to create Toast

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you are calling toast.show() method inside an activity . Because toast is meant to show on user screen and you can not show it outside like service or non activity class . If you are trying to show toast some where in activity your code should work.