# Android Studio OnInfoWindowClickListener not working

Tags: android, dictionary, android-studio

Im using Android Studio and built a new app using the maps activity.

I created a new class and implemented the OnInfoWindowClickListener. Below is my code

public class testListener extends Activity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener {

```
public testListener(GoogleMap mMap) {

    float blue = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE;
    float red = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED;


    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(-26.055984, 28.084833))
                    .title("pick me")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(blue))
    );


    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(-26.058394, 28.078792))
                    .title("Hello World")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(red))
    );
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(testListener.this, "Click Info Window", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Why would the toast message not show? The application ends with Unfortunately, has stopped.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
at com.cinema.movies1.southAfrica.onInfoWindowClick(testListener.java:46)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$10.e(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.f$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
at fno.a(SourceFile:82)
at lxs.b(Unknown Source)
at ltq.g(Unknown Source)
at ltq.a(Unknown Source)
at lnm.b(Unknown Source)
at loh.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
at lbl.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
at lbn.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

try catch exception output:

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
W/System.err﹕ at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:93)
W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
W/System.err﹕ at com.cinema.movies1.southAfrica.onInfoWindowClick(testListener.java:47)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$10.e(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.f$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
W/System.err﹕ at fno.a(SourceFile:82)
W/System.err﹕ at lxs.b(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at ltq.g(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at ltq.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at lnm.b(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at loh.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at lbl.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at lbn.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add this code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        setUpMap();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        float blue = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE;
        float red = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED;

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(-26.055984, 28.084833))
                .title("pick me")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(blue))
        );

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(-26.058394, 28.078792))
                .title("Hello World")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(red))
        );

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Click Info Window", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I didnt. Does that line need to be added after every addMarker? Where does it get added?

Comment: No, when mMap is initialized you should add listener to it only once.

Comment: I added the line of code but my app stops running when I click on the window.

Comment: Change context in Toast. Instead of getBaseContext() put YourActivity.this if you use Activity or getActivity() if you use fragment

Comment: Hi Zoran. My app is still crashing. From the above code snippet should I be getting this issue? I put a try catch around the toast and got the above output from the exception. I wont be using toast going forward I want the listener to open a webpage but thought testing with toast would be easier.

Comment: Are you sure the name of the activity where you load map is testListener? Usually class name starts with capital letter. And also, i refer to this link where context in toast was activity that was not active: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196960/error-when-creating-toast

Comment: I do think its something going wrong with my context. How my project is setup is I have my main activity called MapsActivity which is used to display the map and the users current position. From the setUpMap method i use this line "new TestListener(mMap);" to pass the mMap over to the TestListener class. (I changed the class from testListener to TestListener) The TestListener code you can see above. This class extends Activity and implements the listener. I add 2 markers in the "public TestListener(GoogleMap mMap){}" class. at the end of the markers I put the line:

Comment: mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(SouthAfrica.this);   Once I click the info window the method onInfoWindowClick starts. This is where I have my Toast. Toast.makeText(TestListener.this, "Click Info Window", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  That is all I have in the project. Not sure where im going wrong but there isnt anything complicated happening yet.

Comment: If TestListener extends activity you must call it through intent and not by calling new TestListener(mMap). Also, i think you don't need that class. Put your code from that class to setUpMap method and context would be there MapsActivity.this.

Comment: Does the class need to be added to the manifest file if it extends activity?

Comment: For me to add it to the manifest file it needs public void onCreate(Bundle state) in the class. If I try add the activity to the manifest with the above code it gives the error that I dont have a default constructor. Also when trying to get a context with this line: Context c = getApplicationContext() the app fails immediately.

Comment: And why don't you move all from testListener(GoogleMap mMap) to setUpMap and also move onInfoWindowClick to MapsActivity? Then it would work without crash.

Comment: I got it working. Didnt want it all in one place because the file is going to get too long. 1st class is the main class. 2nd class adds the markers. 3rd class is the listener class. Its working now :)

Comment: Great. I hope you'll mark my answer as one that solved problem